# if condition not working for checking variable is null or not

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, unix, sh

I'm trying to use if-condition in my shell script and have been facing the following issue:

```
status=$echo ps -ef | grep mysql | cut -c10-15 #--> It produces process-id (for e.g. 012345), if exits, or else returns null

echo $status #--> This prints the process id correctly (for e.g. 012345), but it doesn't take value in if condition

if [ -z "$status" ] #--> it should not be NULL as the variable here is 012345  
then
    echo "Need to start server"
else
    echo "Server already up and running"
fi
```

Prints first case even if the "status" variable not NULL.

Comment: use `set -x` to find the problem

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I came to know a new thing about debugging in shell.

Answer (score 1):

`echo $status` isn't outputting the process id; the previous `ps` command is.

You didn't use a command substitution, so you ran the command `ps` with `status` set to the empty string in its environment. When you do run `echo $status`, you just get a blank line, since `status` isn't set.

The code should be

```
status=$(ps -ef | grep mysql | cut -c10-15)
if [ -z "$status" ]; then
  echo "Need to start server"
else
  echo "Server already up and running"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did follow what you told me to do. Doing this too, I'm getting the empty string in variable STATUS. I used `set -x` to debug, it shows 

`status=
' [ '  -z  ' '   ' ] '
`

and fails the if condition.

More help is appreciated. I'm fairly new in this shell scripting.